# WPF DataGrids With Images I need more than 1 column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So far I have this code:

```
    <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Pics}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,-0,0" Width="auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Height="120" Source="{Binding path}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="box" Text="{Binding title}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Now this works quite well, problem is it places the images like this:

X

Title

X

Title

X

Title

Where as I'd like something that utilizes more than one column, I want multiple columns all ultilizing my images, but not mirroring my first column. I would like the images to keep using this row until they hit the border of the window and make a new row automatically

I really hope this is possible and feasible to do, thanks for any help.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, still grasping WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Add the orientation horizontal to stackPanel

```
       <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
          <Image Height="120" Source="{Binding path}" />
          <TextBlock x:Name="box" Text="{Binding title}"></TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
```

check if this works